# AWS Certificate Manager - Do regions matter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-certificate-manager

I already have a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) when only the 1 region was available (think the US-West-1 region?) and currently being used with Cloudfront to host a website for the Australian market.

Now that ACM is [available in more regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/05/aws-certificate-manager-now-available-in-more-regions/), would using a certificate created from the Sydney region have any improvements in performance?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

ACM now supports multiple regions, but that doesn't have any implications for certificates for use with CloudFront.

> To use an ACM certificate with Amazon CloudFront, you must request or import the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) region. ACM certificates in this region that are associated with a CloudFront distribution are distributed to all the geographic locations configured for that distribution.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html

The reason for this is that CloudFront, unlike most AWS services, where the regional implementation of the service is independent of all other regions, has all of its provisioning/administrative infrastructure based in us-east-1.

The *operational* infrastructure is globally distributed and independent, so the centralized management of CloudFront doesn't have performance implications.  If you have performance issues, those should be investigated separately.

The announcement of new regions for ACM doesn't apply to CloudFront.  It's applicable to the other service integrated with ACM, Elastic Load Balancer, which previously only supported ACM certificates in us-east-1 because that was the only region in which they were available, and ELB regions are fully independent of each other.

*Follow-up: This answer was reviewed in May, 2018, two years after it was originally posted, and then again in the summer of 2020.  It is still accurate, as written.  Certificates for CloudFront (as well as for Edge-Optimized deployments in API Gateway, which have a somewhat hidden dependency on CloudFront) are always provisioned in the us-east-1 region of ACM.  There is no compelling reason to expect this to change, as CloudFront's control plane runs in us-east-1.*

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Michael. For the other services like ELB, would it make any difference in performance whether the certificate was obtained from a particular region? Or is it really just a configuration convenience we gain?

Comment: For ELB, there is only one way to use an ACM certificate -- create the certificate in the same region as the load balancer. Until now, ELB could not use ACM certs except in us-east-1, because ACM wasn't in any other region. There's nothing performance related in ACM -- it provisions an SSL certificate for another service (CloudFront or ELB) to use, and it is out of the loop after that, except for annual certificate renewals.  ACM does not handle your site's traffic at all.  That's handled by the actual service you're using, exactly the same as if you were using a cert from another issuer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, would you please consider reviewing this answer as the last edit was made around 2 years ago. Although you have mentioned the official link already here. Just to save some time for future viewers.

Comment: @Prateek - it's still the same, as seen here in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html#decide-procedure-create-subdomain)

Comment: It also seems worth noting that the cert you use for CloudFront now can't be used for the regions for Load Balancers as you get a certificate not found error when attempting to use for an ALB.  This seems like a serious problem IMHO.

Comment: @PlexQ if your balancer isn't in us-east-1, then this is the expected behavior unless I am misinterpreting your comment.  CloudFront-accessible certs need to be in the us-east-1 region, and balancers in other regions can't see them, because ACM is a regional service.

Comment: I will never understand why Amazon can't implement something that will pull your certificate from wherever region it was deployed to into wherever their administrative infrastructure is. Why customers need to know about Amazon's internal infrastructure quirks and be limited by it?

Comment: Isn't this annoying ? If your app is deployed in eu-west-1 with ALB and if it's fronted by a AWS CloudFront, you will essentially need to configure 2 separated certs, one in us-east-1 and the other in eu-west-1

Comment: I've learnt myself today that only certificates created in us-east-1 work. I wonder why AWS still allows certicates to be created AT ALL in other regions. They won't work and only cause confusion.

Comment: @Mako when you are attaching a certificate to a load balancer in another region, the certificate must be created in that other region.  The us-east-1 limitation only applies to CloudFront and edge-optimized API Gateway deployments.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for the info. Now it makes sense why ACM certificates can be created in other regions. But I think AWS should make that clear in their "Request certificate" form. Specifically, I mistakenly created a certificate not in us-east-1 and got an error during "DNS validation" step (pending for validation forever) where CloudFront wasn't involved yet. Now with your info, I could image AWS actually never started the validation when the certificate isn't from us-east-1. But it shown validation started and then pended forever.